Compatibility of driver(s) for AMD E-350 Graphics
I inherited a notebook:

Acer Aspire 3 (E-350) (5250-0441)  with Windows 7 64-bit installed.

I would like to update the drivers to the most recent valid versions.  This is complicated by the fact that it is now a legacy chipset and AMD does not directly support it.
Does anyone know if the bundle described at

https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-6000m-series/amd-radeon-hd-6330m

is compatible?
The description of the E-350 says that it uses an HD 6310.  According to wikipedia, that is classified "ultra-mobile", so ... could that work with the drivers of the "HD 6330M" and could I safely install both of the drivers listed on that AMD page?
Failing that, Driverscape at

https://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/acer/laptops-desktops/aspire-5250/149

shows 2 other drivers dated later than the one I have installed (2011-05-25 / 8.861.0.0).  I've downloaded some other drivers and they all came back "clean" according to Norton 360 specific file scan.

The one shows   vers. 9.0.100.1800 / 2013-09-23.
The other shows vers. 12.100.17.0  / 2013-02-13.

The dates and versions don't seem to jive for those two, so I'm not sure which is the proper "latest and greatest" of those 2 drivers, which are both described as the same as the one installed, namely

AMD Radeon HD 6300 series Graphics

Anyone have any insights/guidance on what I should do here?
Thanks in advance.

A perhaps better-related driver package is found at
E-350 with Radeon™ HD 6310 Drivers & Support.
This software dates from 2015-2016. I don't advise to use third-party
websites for finding drivers.
Before installing, you should verify that this laptop does contain
the Radeon HD 6310. You could use the Windows utility msinfo32.exe
for that (if it exists in Windows 7).

Thank you VERY much, @harrymc!  When I did the lookup on AMD they didn't offer that page.  Also, that EXE is an amazing "admin" tool.  Love it!
